# Audio file returns wrong size value

Tags: android, firebase

I am using media recorder to record audio then I upload it to firebase, by saving the output file content into a byte array, the problem is that the recorded file is correctly saved and played, while in the firebase storage it doesn't work, so I checked out the size of both the saved file on my phone and that I am converting to bytes array ( which are supposed to be the same) I found that getlength returns wrong size! Here is the code

that's the code I am using to record

```
recorder.setAudioSource(android.media.MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
            recorder.setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+lectureTitle.getText().toString()+".mp4");
            recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

            try {
                recorder.prepare();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            recorder.start();
        }
```

The code i am using to convert the file into bytes array so i can upload it

```
File lectureRecorded = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+lectureTitle.getText().toString()+".mp4");

                try {

                    BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(lectureRecorded));

                    if(lectureRecorded.length() > 10*1024*1024){
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"File is too big MAX (10MB)\n a loss will occur",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else {
                        stream = new byte[(int)lectureRecorded.length()];

                        Log.d("AUDIOS",""+lectureRecorded.length());
                        input.read(stream, 0, (int) lectureRecorded.length());
                    }
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                recorder.stop();
                recorder.release();
```

Comment: You did not tell which sizes and lengths you got.

Comment: Further it is a bad idea to first put the bytes of a file in a byte array and then upload the array. Much better is upload the bytes of the file directly in a loop.

Comment: Sorry you want an example of values?

Comment: i don't have the bytes array ! i instead fill it from the file

Comment: It looks as if you read bytes from the file while still recording. That does not look ok.

Comment: Yes i tried to fill the bytes while recording but there is no direct method for that, so i used this wraparound which is supposed to be correct, i mean it's very simple but the length is returned uncorrectly !

Comment: You still did not tell the lengths.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215945/discussion-between-moumenshobakey-and-blackapps).

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistake i just should have read the length after i call release -_-